# Getting "trailing characters" error when trying to parse string with serde_json

Tags: parsing, rust, serde-json

I need to convert a specific string in serde_json::Value, but getting a trailing character error while using:

```
let new_str = "73723235c81ebbec0"
let json_value: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(new_str).unwrap();
```

Error:

```
trailing characters at line 1 column 9
```

Is there any way to convert these kinds of strings to serde_json::Value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the repo for `serde_json`, it appears from their test cases this is expected behavior. For example, see this [test case](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/blob/7e56a406e5e3b2166e6c77a32136d7751093226d/tests/test.rs#L758). Since your string starts with numeric values, it is attempting to parse as a number and then fails when it reaches the 'c' in position 9.

Rather than calling `from_str()`, use `to_value()`. This will give you a `String` variant of the `Value` enum.

```
let json_value: serde_json::Value = serde_json::to_value(&new_str).unwrap();
```

Also, if you use `to_value()`, you can omit the type identifier for your variable, which I believe is probably more idiomatic.

```
let json_value = serde_json::to_value(&new_str).unwrap();
```

Comment: just use `serde_json::Value::from(new_str)` to get a `Value::String` from a `&str`